# Cleanup flatpak repo folder?

Tags: flatpak

After trying to build the [gitg](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gitg) flatpak I noticed my `/var/lib/flatpak/repo` folder has become very large. 
[image]
I'm assuming these are build files? Is there a good way to clean these up?

I'm using Flatpak 1.4.0.

Comment: Which tool did you use to display these storage stats?

Comment: @mYnDstrEAm - I believe it's just the [GNOME Disk Usage Analyser](https://apps.gnome.org/en-GB/app/org.gnome.baobab/) :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`/var/lib/flatpak/` & `~/.local/share/flatpak/` are the system & user install location for installed runtimes (e.g. `org.gnome.Platform`) and applications (e.g. `org.gnome.gitg`). The `repo/` directory is where all the checksum-ed binary files are stored, it's like a git repo.  They are not the build files unless you include the downloaded `org.gnome.Sdk//master` runtime, which would be installed here. But the SDK is shared and not specific to gitg.

If you built with `flatpak-builder` they would be in a folder called `.flatpak-builder` & the `build` folder (what ever you called it). So if you ran the following in a directory like `~/gitg-build-folder/`:

```sh
flatpak-builder --force-clean --repo=gitg-repo build org.gnome.gitgDevel.json
```

Delete `~/gitg-build-folder/build` & `~/gitg-build-folder/.flatpak-builder` to remove any build files produced during building gitg.

If you don't need to build anything in the future you could delete `org.gnome.Sdk//master`, however, a lot of the files are de-duplicated as `org.gnome.Platform` is also installed. You might also have the `*.Debug` SDK extension installed which would take a lot of space.

Answer from duplicate question on Flatpak GitHub:
https://github.com/flatpak/flatpak/issues/2945#issuecomment-499498706

Answer (score 26):

For those landing here who arent building stuff, `/var/lib/flatpak/repo` is also where every flatpak installs ends up, and when you run upgrades it doesn't clean itself up.  For `--user` installed packages it would be `~/.local/share/flatpak/`.

Discovered that answer on this [post](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2019/02/how-to-remove-unused-flatpak-runtimes.html).

```
flatpak uninstall --unused
```

Before

```
[root@laptop flatpak]# du -sh .
8.4G    .
```

After

```
[root@laptop flatpak]# du -sh .
4.3G    .
```

Comment: Great point. 
Maybe also mention `~/.local/share/flatpak/` for user installs.  Small typo: It's flatpak, not flatpack.

Comment: More drastic, but `flatpak uninstall --all` reduced `/var/lib/flatpak/repo/` 2.6G.

Answer (score 10):

Fixed my greedy Flatpak problem, for what it's worth: I managed to clean like 20 Gb of garbage (/var/lib/flatpak/repo/objects), a bunch of tiny files. I started by uninstalling all the applications that I had installed there, but it didn't make much difference.
Without applications and only with runtimes, it was still the same. Used the **flatpak uninstall --unused** command, which removes runtimes and extensions not used by installed applications (I didn't have any left, so everything was removed). Despite this, there was no big difference on the hard drive.
Finally, the command **sudo flatpak repair**, which is to fix inconsistencies, is what cleared almost 20 GB.
I had previously tried it without success. I guess by deleting the apps, Flatpak just became aware of that garbage.
Although I don't need them anymore, because I installed them directly on the system, I reinstalled the Flatpak applications (curious to see what would happen) that I had and everything works fine and only taking up something like 1GB.

My Flatpak version: 1.10.7

Comment: I didn't have any flatpak app installed at the user-level (only a few system wide), but I noticed flatpak took several GB in my `~/.local/share/flatpak` folder. I finally got it to clean up with `flatpak repair --user`.